# 'My Leave Requests' - how to adjust default settings?

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I am implementing a standard SAP Fiori Application named '[My Leave Requests 3](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F1311A%27)/S9OP)' into a SAP Fiori Launchpad on-premise.

I have followed the installation and configuration steps listed in the documentation and the application is up and running.

The applications default behavior uses a simple-approval process, thus one approver can be selected from one rendered input field as can be seen here:

[image: F1311 approvers field]

The documentation states that the application supports multi-level-approval. Both frontend (SAPUI5) and backend (ABAP) already include code to handle multi-level-scenarios. This can also be seen in the prior screenshot: next to the input field are visible but disabled buttons.

Since all the logic for a multi-level-scenario exists, the application does not need a custom extension.

Thus, there must be a way to configure the default behavior or allow for MLA in what I assume would be a customizing menu within SAP NetWeaver.

Where can I adjust the application to use the implemented but non-default behavior?

Comment: Can you check what this view element is bound to? Surely the enabled/disabled comes from some kind of model. To inspect UI5 controls you can either use the built in shortcut `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `S` or the browser extension [UI5 Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ui5-inspector/bebecogbafbighhaildooiibipcnbngo?hl=de)

Comment: Most probably for MLA you need a working hierarchy in HR module, it is not said explicitly in Fiori Library but is implied. Check [extensibility section](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_ON-PREMISE/c6c3ffd90792427a9fee1a19df5b0925/9edf4c58b33240f88fc69f9e3cd9cca8.html?locale=en-US&version=1709%20000) in app documentation, you may need to implement `HCMFAB_B_COMMON` BAdi for this

Comment: Hi, you should be able to define the possibility to set the next processor when editing the appropriate entry in V_T554S_WEB. There you have to change the value for the subtype (absence type) you want to have in MLA scenario and the corresponding WEBMO value of the employee group for the field "Requester May Change Next Agent". If allowed, you should be able to define next approver if you want. Could you check?